# iOS location data in UIImage metadata isn't handling negative CGFloat/double

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, cllocationmanager

After some grueling effort, I got GPS data injected into my UIImage EXIF using `CLLocationManager`. It was truly a terrible experience, I don't personally recommend it.

I'm using the code below this to write the image to the assets library, and ere's a log output of my NSDictionary of metadata (object #5, {GPS}) at a breakpoint write before it's written to the camera roll:

```
Printing description of [5].key:
{GPS}
Printing description of [5].value:
{
    Altitude = "-1.606232";
    Latitude = "49.86973495227272";
    LatitudeRef = N;
    Longitude = "-125.1198035572889";
    LongitudeRef = W;
}
```

Here's the save method:

```
- (void)saveToCameraRoll
{
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // Captured that NSDictionary excerpt from this next line on 'metadata' var        
    NSDictionary* metadata = [defaults objectForKey:kImageMetadata];
    if (_imageToSave) {
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
        [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[_imageToSave CGImage] metadata:metadata completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                // Darn, bad things happened
            }
            else
            {
                // Wahoo!
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

And the location position updated delegate method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    CGFloat currentLatitude = [manager location].coordinate.latitude;
    CGFloat currentLongitude = [manager location].coordinate.longitude;
    CGFloat currentAltitude = [manager location].altitude;

    //For GPS Dictionary
    if(!_locationData)
        _locationData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [_locationData setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:currentLatitude] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude];
    [_locationData setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:currentLongitude] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude];

    NSString* ref;
    if (currentLatitude <0.0)
        ref = @"S";
    else
        ref =@"N";
    [_locationData setValue:ref forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitudeRef];

    if (currentLongitude <0.0)
        ref = @"W";
    else
        ref =@"E";

    [_locationData setValue:ref forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitudeRef];

    [_locationData setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentAltitude] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSAltitude];

}
```

So all is well, and I look at the saved photo: latitude and it's all good, but then I look at longitude, and it's `0`.

My guess? Somewhere it isn't liking that longitude is a negative number. I don't know much about geo-coordinates, but maybe you do, and maybe you'd like to help me get out of the English Channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huzzah!

Because I was declaring the S and W ref values, I clued in that the way EXIF is handling GPS data might require absolute values.

The solution was to instead of using the raw float value, I used `fabs()` to get the absolute float value.

```
...

[_locationData setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:fabs(currentLatitude)] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude];
[_locationData setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:fabs(currentLongitude)] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude];

...
```